# TouchEvents not Registering Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04

Tags: actionscript-3, ubuntu, multi-touch

I am trying to create a multitouch application for Ubuntu with As3 (air files).

I have successfully supported multitouch events in Windows systems.

The problem is that although my application supports multitouch when I run it in Ubuntu only single mouse clicks are registered.

I have used Planetary and other multitouch applications to check the functionality of my hardware and it supports multitouch. Also Touchegg registers correctly two finger touches.

Any ideas?

Comment: AIR does not support linux systems since 2.6 so why would you even bother? And btw this is also your answer.

Comment: 2.6 features are enough for me. So this is not an answer.

Comment: 2.6 does not support touch events.